# Why does the series $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{m q^{m^2}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove the following series converge ($0<q<1$)?

$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{m q^{m^2}}
$$

Comment: To downvoters: feel free to explain. Is this kind of questions not suitable for asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Root Test. The $m$-th root of the $m$-th term is $(m^{1/m})q^m$, which goes to $0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For $m\ge 1$, if $0<q<1$, $mq^{m^2} \le mq^m$; this converges by comparison with a differentiated geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum mq^{m^2}\leq\sum m^2q^{m^2}\leq\sum xq^x
$$
which converges.